# Non-constant entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

> Does there exist a non-constant entire function $f$ which is constant for $|z|<1?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This follows from the [Identity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).